# Modify variable in EDT

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, awt, edt

My loop is not stopping when i set the number[0] = ten, the thread for the while loop can't see the number being changed when the jbutton is pressed, How do i fixed this? I believe the thread is being blocked.

```
    public class A{

        private int[] number = new number[1];
        private number_game gui;


        public A(){
        }

        public void thread_loop(){

            gui = new number_game();
            gui.the_game(number);

            Thread nums = new Thread(){

                public void run(){

                    while(number[0]!= 10){

                           if(number != 10)
                              System.out.println("wrong number")
                    }

                };nums.start();

            } 
        }

    }

public class number_game extends Jframe{

......

    public number_game(){}

    / creating gui
    public void the_game(int [] guess){

       .............
       checkguess.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                  guess[1] = 10;
                  dispose();

            }
        });
   }
}

public class main{
    public static void main(String[]args) {

    A nums_play = new A();
    nums_play.thread_loop();
    }

}
```

Comment: Accesses to a shared variable (number in this case) should be synchronized.

Comment: or use an AtomicInteger instead of an array

Comment: synchronize the function?

Comment: Not the whole function with a loop in it; only the accesses to number. Or make a getNumber and setNumber and declare them as synchronized.It would be simpler and faster to use an AtomicInteger though.

Comment: gotcha! i well try that

Comment: I'd consider using an `AtomicInteger` rather than trying to use an array

Comment: that didnt work sadly,I thought by passing an array both the threads will see the change. I changed and passed an AtomicInteger instead but that didnt work either

Comment: `Jframe` isn't a thing. GUI code needs to run in the Event Dispatch Thread, as explained in the Java Tutorial. Others mentioned synchronization. It's better to implement `Runnable` than to extend `Thread`. You really should follow the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping that this is just some threading practice.  To share values across threads you need to make sure that the access is synchronized properly, while there are a number of ways to do it, one of the simplest might be to use a `AtomicInteger` which takes care of all the multi-thread access functionality for you.

I've also included a simple "lock" class which means that the `Thread` doesn't "free wheel" out of control and provides a means for the UI to alert the thread that a change has occurred, to which it can then process the value.

All this is shared across the thread monitor and UI classes.

I strongly recommend having a look at the [Concurrency Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) which covers this information in more detail

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public class CommonLock {

        private ReentrantLock lock;
        private Condition condition;

        public CommonLock() {
            lock = new ReentrantLock();
            condition = lock.newCondition();
        }

        protected void lock() {
            lock.lock();
        }

        protected void unlock() {
            lock.unlock();
        }

        public void await() throws InterruptedException {
            lock();
            try {
                condition.await();
            } finally {
                unlock();
            }
        }

        public void signal() {
            lock();
            try {
                condition.signal();
            } finally {
                unlock();
            }
        }

    }

    public Test() throws HeadlessException {
        CommonLock lock = new CommonLock();
        AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger(0);
        ThreadMonitor monitor = new ThreadMonitor(value, lock);
        monitor.start();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane(value, lock));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private final AtomicInteger value;
        private final CommonLock lock;

        public TestPane(AtomicInteger value, CommonLock lock) {
            this.value = value;
            this.lock = lock;
            JButton btn = new JButton("Pick");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    value.addAndGet(2);
                    lock.signal();
                }
            });
            add(btn);
        }

    }

    public class ThreadMonitor {

        private final AtomicInteger value;
        private final CommonLock lock;

        public ThreadMonitor(AtomicInteger value, CommonLock lock) {
            this.value = value;
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        public void start() {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            lock.await();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                        int number = value.get();
                        if (number == 10) {
                            break;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Bad Guess");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Good guess");
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

The example will increment the value (from `0`) in steps of `2`, allow you to see the thread processing it until it reaches `10`

If you wanted to, you could create a single class which emcampasses the `CommonLock` and `AtomicInteger`, making the management slightly easier, but I'll leave that up to you